# Image graph in d3

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I have a JSON file that holds image file names (jpg) and their 2D coordinates with all the images in a folder. How do I plot those images on a 2D plane at the specified coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let imagine following json array

```
[{
   x: 100,
   y: 100,
   url: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/...'
}, {
   x: 110,
   y: 110,
   url: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/...'
}, ...]
```

it is very easy place images on plane in d3:

```js
let w = 450, h = 150;

let data = d3.range(10).map(i => {
  return {
    x: Math.random()*w,
    y: Math.random()*h,
    url: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK1my.png?s=24&g=1'
}});

d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h)
  .selectAll('image')
  .data( data )
  .enter()
  .append('image')
  .attr('xlink:href', d => d.url)
  .attr('x', d => d.x)
  .attr('y', d => d.y)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```